# Hosting sites on mapped drives

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, mappeddrive

My question is simple, We have an web server running windows 2008 with IIS. We map a network drive from our storage facilities to it and host the site that way.

I am wondering if there are likely to be any performance issues doing this? We have bench marked I/O's and are currently happy with the results over the mapped drive. Just wondering if there is anything else I should watch out for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without meaning to be obtuse, but you've absolutely answered your own question. To my knowledge, there are no real underlying issues doing this - it'd probably be better with a SAN so that you get a proper LUN and therefore drive letter presented to the server, but this should work okay.

The key issue will simply be throughput and if you've tested it and you're happy, then that's great.

There is, however an article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257174) that implies you may be better off using full UNC paths rather than mapped drives.